# Replacement for CoreWLAN deprecated features

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, corewlan

I've just looked at [CoreWLAN's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/) and I've seen that several methods of [CWInterface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWInterface_reference/index.html) are deprecated since OS X 10.10. However the documentation doesn't mention any replacement for these features. Any idea of where I should give a look?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `CWWiFiClient`. Unfortunately I was not able to track down the class reference for this class on the developer website - seems it's not there yet. The good news is that you can access it through the code navigation feature of Xcode.

However, there appears to be a bug such that entitlements are not granted. This even extends to non-sandboxed apps. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495227/using-startmonitoringeventwithtype-error-in-the-effort-to-detect-wifi-ssid-cha) and [this question on the Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11307).